# Merge changes into Git repository using tarballs

Tags: git

What is the easiest way to manage a git repository without a proper upstream? In my case, the upstream is a single old codger who refuses to make a repository and just releases tarballs occasionally. I still want to be able to merge in his changes to my repo, but how do I do this in the most elegant 'git' way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the tarballs and copy over all the files into your repo and commit.

For handling deleted/renamed files in the tarballs, you can use options similar to `--delete` in `rsync` in your tool of choice to ensure that files that are present in the destination (your repo), but not in the source (extracted tarball), are deleted

Comment: That is only a partial solution.  If the new release deletes or renames a file/directory, then both the old release's file and the new release's file/directory will appear.

Comment: @optikos - Can you suggest a better one, though?